# Sectional and Ricci curvature on product manifolds

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, products, curvature, tangent-spaces

I am reading a paper on Euclidian cones (https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0197), and there's this example (2.7):

Let $M:=\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathbb{S}^2\big)\times\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathbb{S}^2)$. Let then $u_1, u_2$ be an orthonormal basis of of $T_x\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathbb{S}^2\big)$ and $v_1,v_2$ analogously for $T_y\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\mathbb{S}^2\big)$. Then an orthonormal basis of $T_{(x,y)}M$ is given by $\{\bar{u_1},\bar{u_2},\bar{v_1},\bar{v_2}\}$ with $\bar{u_i}=(u_i,0)$ and $\bar{v_i}=(0,v_i)$. In this basis:$$Sec_{(x,y)}(\bar{u_1},\bar{u_2})=Sec_{(x,y)}(\bar{v_1},\bar{v_2})=3$$and $0$ in all the other cases so for each $\xi\in T_{(x,y)}M$ we have $Ric_{(x,y)}(\xi,\xi)=3$ (this also appears in the Petersen's book).

But now comes the thing that I do not understand: let $N:=(M\times[0,\infty)/M\times\{0\})\backslash\{O\}$ (you identify the points with second coordinate $0$ and remove the origin to get a "punctured cone") so that given $r>0$ an orthonormal basis of $T_{(x,y,r)}N$ is given by $\{\hat{u_1},\hat{u_2},\hat{v_1},\hat{v_2},\hat{w}\}$ with $\hat{u_i}=\frac{1}{r}(u_i,0,0)$, $\hat{v_i}=\frac{1}{r}(0,v_i,0)$ and $\hat{w}=(0,0,1)$. In this basis they claim that$$Sec_{(x,y,r)}(\hat{u_1},\hat{u_2})=\frac{2}{r^2},\quad Sec_{(x,y,r)}(\hat{u_1},\hat{v_1})=-\frac{1}{r^2}=Sec_{(x,y,r)}(\hat{u_1},\hat{v_2}),\quad Sec_{(x,y,r)}(\hat{u_1},\hat{w})=0.$$So now the Ricci is $0$ but what I do not understand is why the scalar curvatures changed from $0$ to $-\frac{1}{r^2}$ and the first one to $\frac{2}{r^2}$.

Comment: The metric on the cone matters, but the authors' notation $\cos(d(x, x') \wedge \pi)$, which appears in the topological metric on $N$,$$d(x,s), (x',t)) = \sqrt{s^2+t^2-2st\cos(d(x,x') \wedge \pi)},$$doesn't seem to be explained in the paper. (It's presumably standard for some value of _standard_.) If you know what the notation means could you please add the metric and explanation to the question?

Comment: The $min$ is there because if the metric measure space has Ricci curvature bounded below by a positive constant then the Myers' theorem holds: the diameter of $M$ is bounded by $\pi$ (or some renormalized value).
Here there's a similar approach on how to derive that (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.09575.pdf, Remark 2.1) but using a Lorentzian-type metric, but I think the construction is the same at end if you start with the usual Euclidian metric